# Airflow 2.1.0 returning "Refused to delete permission view assoc with role..."

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ecs

I migrated from `Airflow 1.10.15` to `Airflow 2.1.0`. I followed the guidelines in Airflow docs to migrate with that release as a bridge version. Everything works like a charm but i receive the following output in the logs:

[image]

I did not experienced any bug or something at least for now. I can't find any info about this in the airflow community neither in the docs. Any idea of what does it mean? And how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an annoying warning that shows up during migration from 1.10.x to 2.x, but it's not reflective of an actual problem, so you can disregard it.

The reason for this is that I wrote a migration to standardize permission names between the UI and the API. This involves unwinding existing permissions from existing roles and adding them back with the updated names. The warning means a migration is attempting to run a step out of sequence.

This is a known issue that has proved surprisingly tricky to fix, but it won't prevent the proper permissions from getting added. I'll try to add the fix to an upcoming bug release (2.1.1 or 2.1.2).

Comment: Hi @jtimmins - is there any updates? log still exist in v2.2.3 `WARNING - Refused to delete permission view, assoc with role exists DAG Runs.can_create Admin`

Comment: Hi @jtimmins - it happens also in version 2.2.5 - is it expected to be fixed?